# getting an id through another row value

Tags: php, sql

i want to get the donor when donator_1 or donator_2 is selected and also get the data from another table using donor as the primary key  [image]

i have tried the following but its not selecting the particular id, it is selecting the  whole column

```
$result3 = $DBcon->query("SELECT username, email, Phone_number, subcription FROM tbl_users join mergeing on tbl_users.user_id = mergeing.donor where mergeing.donor  = mergeing.donor");

while($row = $result3->fetch_array())
{
  echo $row['username']; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It shows you the whole column because in your query you're using

`where mergeing.donor = mergeing.donor`

that will match the whole table.

So just change it inserting the donor ID you're looking for

`where mergeing.donor = 1`

Comment: how do i make it to automatically get the row donor

Comment: @imm do you need to match a specified donor id?